# get random background image using php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get a random background image using php. Thats done easy ([Source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image/)):

```
<?php
  $bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' );
  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); 
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; 
?>
```

Lets optimize it to choose all background-images possible inside a folder:

```
function randImage($path)
{
    if (is_dir($path)) 
    {
        $folder = glob($path); // will grab every files in the current directory
        $arrayImage = array(); // create an empty array

        // read throught all files
        foreach ($folder as $img) 
        {
            // check file mime type like (jpeg,jpg,gif,png), you can limit or allow certain file type   
            if (preg_match('/[.](jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/i', basename($img))) { $arrayImage[] = $img; }
        }

        return($arrayImage); // return every images back as an array
    }
    else
    {
        return('Undefine folder.');
    }
}

$bkgd = randImage('image/');
$i = rand(0, count($bkgd)-1); // while generate a random array
$myRandBkgd = "$bkgd[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
```

As I am using this inside a wordpress theme, I need to set the `$bkgd = randImage('image/');` relative to my theme folder. I thought, I could do that using:

```
$bgfolder = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/backgrounds/';
bkgd = randImage($bgfolder);
```

When I test `$bgfolder`, which seems to be the most important part, using `var_dump()` I receive a not working path:

```
http://yw.hiamovi-client.com/wp-content/themes/youthwork string(19) "/images/backgrounds"
```

Somehow there is a `space` before the `/images/backgrounds/`. I have no idea where this comes from! …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change

```
$myRandBkgd = "$bkgd[$i]";
```

to

```
$myRandBkgd = $bkgd[$i];
```

---

If that doesn't help, use `var_dump()` instead of `echo()` to dump some of your variables along the way and check if the output corresponds to your expectations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! Both does not help. My output is at follows `http://pathtotheme.de/wp-content/themes/mytheme string(1) "U"`

Comment: Well, throw a couple `var_dump()`s into your code – i.e. before `return($arrayImage)` – and look for yourself ;)

Comment: Thats a smart trick to find errors! Currently the whole function returns `Undefine folder.`, because my path is not correct. Testing it using `<?php var_dump($bgfolder) ?>` shows, that there is a space coming out of nowhere. I have edited my question and added this detail!